# problemas de compilación en PASCAL

Tags: pascal

Tengo problemas en la compilación en Pascal. En la imagen se aprecia la descripción del error; pero como nunca había programado en este lenguaje, me cuesta entender el error. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería... Saludos a todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega tu codigo en la pregunta no envies screenshot

Comment: prueba parentesis a ambos lados del `or`, la precedencia de operadores puede estar haciendo que compare un int con un bool (es lo q dice el error)

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer comparaciones múltiples en pascal, necesitas separar las condiciones entre paréntesis

en tu caso `if (Cero[j] =15) or (Uno[i]>1)`

Puedes tener más información en este artículo
https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Pascal/Control_condicional